# facebook long live token renewal

Tags: ios, facebook, access-token

I am using Facebook iOS SDK 3.1.

From the FB [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens)

> Apps created from our Mobile SDKs (Android and iOS), from Desktop Apps and the server-side Login flow automatically get long-lived User Access Tokens. This long-lived token refreshes and extends each time the user triggers the auth flow.

The token has a validity of 60 days.

I have the current implementation:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

  if (![FBSession activeSession].isOpen) {
    if ([FBSession activeSession].state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) {
      [[FBSession activeSession] openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                               FBSessionState status,
                                                               NSError *error) {}];
    }
   }
}
```

, but this only gets triggered when the app is launched for the very first time or after when it's killed.

A couple of questions here:

1. What should be the correct step to extend the token when the app is being used but no FB calls are made for 60 days.
2. Assuming the app is running or goes to background mode and the user does not use any FB features such as share/logout/login, will the token be automatically renewed?
3. When accessing FB calls through the SDK, will the token be automatically renewed and made available in FBSession?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to clarify, with Facebook SDK 3.1, the access token is refreshed in the background, when API calls are made or during the auth flow. Refreshes happen after about a day from the last refresh time.

1. If no FB calls are made for that long, and the token expires, you should reauthorize the user. This may mean that they are taken through a re-auth flow. So the moment they make an FB-related call and it fails due to an expired token you should reauth (see also https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/errors/). You should build this into your app anyway because there could be different ways that the token is expired or invalidated.
2. No, it's refreshed on API calls (see answer to 1).
3. Yes, after a certain time after the last refresh.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

As for #1, they may also be prompted a login dialog in certain cases when the relevant permission or app has been removed?

Comment: how can i reauthorize the user? i am having the same problem. i don't know how to do it. can you please explain the steps?

Comment: How can I see actual expired time for long-live token? My steps:

1. Login via WebAuthenticationBroker (UWP - Windows 10)

2. Get shot-live token

3. Get long-live token. Expired after 2 month.

How can I know than I should clear data and invoke broker again? And why I can't refresh token?